# Very Simple Slider animation broken with less than three slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slider

I have a pretty basic slider here that I got from: http://codepen.io/Abbogaming1353/pen/CxgIE

The issue is that with less than three slides, the animation is messed up and I can see the background during animation rather than the next slide smoothly pushing the first to the left. This happens even in the original slider if I just use two slides. I'll attach my edited code so you can see what I have going on:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="index.js"></script></head>

<style type="text/css">
#sliderBackground
{
    width: 968px;
    height: 370px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #0CC;
}

#slider
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 940px;
    height: 340px;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
}

#slider ul
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 940px;
    height: 340px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 340px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    padding: 4% 3%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="sliderBackground">
    <div id="slider">
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li>SLIDE 2</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

I assume the issue is with the JavaScript, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
```

With this it will work

```
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth});
```

**Edit 2**

replace this line

```
$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth});  
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul'); // this line to be changed
```

To this

```
$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth});
$('#slider ul li:first-child').prependTo('#slider ul'); // from :last-child to :first-child
```

Comment: This worked, except now slide 2 is showing first. Not just slide 2, but what ever slide is last. If there are 4 slides, it goes to slide 4, which then proceeds to slide 1 (which should happen, I just want it to start on slide 1). Thank you for your help, any idea why the slides are out of order now?

Answer (score 0):

the solution of Vitorino does work for the Moveright, but if you move left you have the same problem. I suggest you open up the inspector and search for "ul" then you will see that with only 2 elements in your ul, your ul has always the appended li on the left side. 
So you need to put the .css in the .click event of each button.

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });


    if(slideCount>2){
      $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth});
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });
  }else
    {  
      $('a.control_prev').hide();
      $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth});
    function moveLeft2() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: 0
        }, 200);
        $('a.control_prev').hide();
        $('a.control_next').show();
    };

    function moveRight2() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: -slideWidth
        }, 200);
      $('a.control_prev').show();
        $('a.control_next').hide();
    };
    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft2();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight2();
    });
    }

});
```

This way when you click right, the ul will be at the normal position(the 2. li will be on the right side).
I hope you understand

Comment: Wait a second. This still does not work like it should. Give me 10 minutes

Comment: There is no clicking left or right, I have it set with no controls to auto play and slide to the left.

Comment: The code is posted now works with and without controls. Give it a try

Comment: Since I am not really that familiar with JS, whenever I paste this in, it's telling me there is a syntax error at the end. I tried pasting it in a few different ways/places. Obviously this is meant to pasted in between something and I'm not understanding. Any chance you could post the whole thing and not just an excerpt, or tell me where it goes.

Comment: Please try to copy the html and css of the website you posted and try again. With the html and css from your site it works perfectly fine